# Aligning numbers by decimal points in table columns

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, punctuation, siunitx, dcolumn

Let me begin by stating that I did google the answers (and I'll reference to them soon). Yet each of the resources I found discussed one particular method, I'm interested in a comparison of the approaches.

So far, I've found three ways to deal with this problem:

- split the number into two columns (integer and fractional parts), as documented [here](http://ryanmlayer.wordpress.com/2009/10/05/aligning-on-decimal-points-an-example-of-the-specifier/) or [here](http://www.volkerschatz.com/tex/halign.html). The LaTeX code is simple, but the approach is a pain when it comes to copying and pasting tables from external sources.
- use [`dcolumn`](http://ctan.org/pkg/dcolumn) manually
- use Mike Zhang's automatic [converter](http://blog.mikezhang.com/dcolumn/processtable.cgi) ([description](http://blog.mikezhang.com/2008/09/08/decimal-point-alignment-in-latex)). I have yet to test it.

What do most people use? `dcolumn`? Are there other options?

Answer (score 169, accepted):

The newest option is using the `S` column type of the [`siunitx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=3.2]}% syntax for siunitx v2; for v1 use "tabformat"
555 \\
7.77 \\
99.9
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Comment: Indeed, in version 2 of `siunitx` you will find that there is an implementation that is ~ the same as the `dcolumn` one, plus a second approach more similar to `rccol`.

Comment: This looks great.  I can't get it to work though.  With pdflatex from texlive 2009 on OSX, I got:

    ``! Package xkeyval Error: `table-format' undefined in families `key'.``

Comment: Seems like you're using `siunitx` v.1.x (the current version is 2). Try `tabformat` instead of `table-format`.

Comment: @lockstep: I hope you read this. I've found that if the cell value is enclosed within \textbf{}, the decimal point alignment doesn't work any more (everything is flushed left). Is there a way to achieve both? I want to highlight a particular column, hence the bolding. Thanks.

Comment: BTW: Newest table package [tabu](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabu) supports `siunitx`, e.g., `S` columns inside `X` columns.

Comment: Just a note: table headers gave me an error, so I had to wrap them in a `\multicolumn{1}{c}{name}`

Comment: in response to a comment by daniel kullmann Nov 15 '11 at 10:31 The official way of getting siunitx to ignore bits of text, like headers, is to just wrap them in braces; i.e. `{name}` will work just as well as `\multicolumn{1}{c}{name}`. See for instance http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3709/puzzling-error-while-using-sunitx-in-a-tabular-environment#comment88988_3710 (would still like newbies to be able to post comments!)

Comment: I fiddled around with siunitx for this purpose, and it seemed like using an elephant gun to kill a fly. I also couldn't find any way to make it believe that commas weren't decimal-place markers.

Comment: what if I want one number to be in bold? it ruins the alignment...

Comment: I have trouble using this for multi-column `tabular` and `array`. Is it possible?

Comment: I feel like someone should mention what the `table-format=3.2` does: The numbers in `table-format=X.Y` specify the number of digits on each side of the decimal marker. You need to set them to the largest number of digits on each side in the respective column to avoid [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/468585/table-formatting-using-siunitx) problem.

Answer (score 27):

Even though it's already been mentioned in the posting, it's worth discussing the [dcolumn](http://ctan.org/pkg/dcolumn) package in more detail. The package provides a column type called `D` that performs alignment on the decimal marker. The `D` column type takes three inputs: the input decimal marker (usually `.` or `,`), the output decimal marker (again, usually `.` or `,`), and the number of digits before and after the decimal marker. If the input and output decimal markers are always the same -- e.g., always `.` -- it's useful to set up a short-hand as follows:

```
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
```

Here's a full MWE that's based on @lockstep's code -- indeed, with this simple example the outputs of `S[table-format=3.2]` and `D{.}{.}{3.2}` are *identical* :

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{d{3.2}}
555 \\
7.77 \\
99.9
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The only difference I see between dcolumn and siunitx is that for column headers composed of text, you can use both `\multicolumn{c}{1}{header}` or `{header}` in siunitx whereas in dcolumn, the only option is `\multicolumn{c}{1}{header}`. This is just a minor thing.

Comment: @DenisCousineau - In practice, if you find yourself writing a lot of `\multicolumn{1}{c}{...}` "wrappers", it pays to set up a shortcut macro, say via `\newcommand{\mc}[1]{{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}`, so one can type `\mc{...}`. That's only two more keyboard strokes than `{...}`. :-)

Comment: @Mico Exactly the MWE which I was looking for! But then you give a guy a hand, he starts getting ideas and wants _two arms_: **1.** I would like to align _signed_ decimal numbers, and **2.** for the next to last line, I would like the standard dotted line that says etc.

Comment: @schremmer - If you want to stay with the `dcolumn` machinery, you just need to add one extra column for the sign symbol. E.g., to handle numbers such as `-1245.56`, you'd set `d{5.2}`. To typeset `...` in  a `d` column, just write `\multicolumn{1}{c}{\dots}` or, using the `\mc` device I mentioned in a comment above, define the `\mc` shortcut macro in the preamble and write `\mc{\dots}` in a table cell. If you need the ultimate in formatting control of numeric data in table cells, do consider using the `siunitx` package and its `S` column type, though.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for a prompt answer which works and that even I can understand. But why do $+1.0$, $+10.0$, etc work but $+0.1$, $0.01$, etc right-align, that is the 1s line up? Just a bit curious. But, again,  without $$  everything works fine of course.

Comment: @schremmer - The `dcolumn` package expects the cells to be in math mode. Hence, `$+10.0$ should throw a syntax error.