# siunitx: aligning numbers by decimal points in tables doesn't work for bolded or italicized numbers

Tags: tables, formatting, horizontal-alignment, punctuation, siunitx

This is a follow-up question for [Aligning numbers by decimal points in table columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2746/old-question-aligning-numbers-by-decimal-points-in-table-columns).

User lockstep provided this solution:

```
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=3.2]}
555 \\
7.77 \\
99.9
\end{tabular}
```

The accepted answer worked; but I subsequently found that it did not if the numbers are bolded in the table (i.e. within `\textbf{}`). In this case, everything is flushed left. 
I do need to use bold face in my case (to direct the user's eyes towards a particular column in a larger table).

To give an example, below is a test table and the output.

```
\begin{table}
   \begin{tabular}{@{}l S[table-format=3.2] S[table-format=3.2]@{}}
          \toprule
          \textbf{Foo} & \textbf{Normal} & \textbf{Bold}  \\
          \midrule
          foo1 & 111 & \textbf{111}\\
          foo2 & 222.2 & \textbf{222.2}\\
          foo3  & 3.33 & \textbf{3.33}\\
          foo4  & 4 & \textbf{4}\\
          foo5  & 5.5 & \textbf{5.5}\\
          \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Output:

[image]

I checked the [manual](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.pdf) but didn't find anything about this. I suppose the presence of the markup confuses the parser to believe there cell is not a number, but this is mere speculation and I could be wrong.

Thanks in advance for suggestions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to use the `detect-all` package option and to add `\bfseries` to the column declaration instead of using `\textbf` for every cell. (Sorry for not answering before - I wrongly assumed you wanted a single cell in bold.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[detect-all]{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}lS[table-format=3.2]>{\bfseries}S[table-format=3.2]@{}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Foo} & \textbf{Normal} & \textbf{Bold} \\
    \midrule
    foo1 & 111 & 111 \\
    foo2 & 222.2 & 222.2 \\
    foo3 & 3.33 & 3.33 \\
    foo4 & 4 & 4 \\
    foo5 & 5.5 & 5.5 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @lockstep, thank you for [detect-all], spend 4 hrs and couldn't fix it before.

Answer (score 12):

this came up recently in another forum and Joseph came up with a solution. I include his aswer. the key is to use the `etoolbox` package and `\robustify\bfseries`

> Okay, the way that `siunitx` works with
>   formatting is a little complex as it
>   has to pick up which macros to expand
>   and which not to. As e-TeX is
>   required, I've taken the attitude that
>   things 'not to expand' can be e-TeX
>   `\protected`. For the case in hand, you
>   therefore need to make `bfseries`
>   robust. Something like
>
> ```
> \documentclass{article}
> \usepackage{colortbl,etoolbox,siunitx,xcolor}
> \robustify\bfseries \sisetup{
> detect-weight = true , locale = DE , }
> \begin{document}
>
> \begin{table} \sisetup{
> group-separator = ., table-format = 5.0,
> table-number-alignment = right , }
> \begin{tabular}{S[table-format = 8.0,
> table-number-alignment = right]SlSS} \rowcolor[gray]{0.9}
> \bfseries 1234567 & \bfseries 12345 &
> \bfseries Test & \bfseries 12345 &
> \bfseries 12345 \\ 1234567 & 12345 &
> Test & 12345 & 12345 \\
> \end{tabular}
> \end{table}
>
> \end{document}
> ```
>
> should do the job. I've got a bug fix
>   of siunitx to do, so I'll add a note
>   on this to the documentation. Let me
>   know if the above works for you.

Comment: Well, I actually had the question lockstep thought the OP had which is to only typeset single cells in bold. This works wonderfully, thanks!