# Why do I have to choose between global and local settings for siunitx tabular behaviour?

Tags: tables, siunitx

This is a follow up to [Numbers in tables: align by decimal point *and* flush right?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2779/numbers-in-tables-align-by-decimal-point-and-flush-right/2782#2782).

In a tabular set with `siunitx`, I can give formatting options or in the `\sisetup{}` command or in the `\begin{tabular}` environment options. Why is that so? I would like to give global settings and still be able to modify single columns.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
per-mode=symbol-or-fraction,
locale=DE,
sticky-per
]{siunitx} 
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \caption{Comparing global and local settings}
    \sffamily
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.48\linewidth}
    \caption{Global}
    \sffamily
    \sisetup{detect-family, table-number-alignment = right}
    \rowcolors{2}{white}{gray!20}
    \centering   
        \begin{tabular}{S[table-format=6.0] S[table-format=2.0] S[table-format=4.0]}\hline
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Foo} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$F$ in \si{\hertz}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\sigma$ in \si{\newton\per\meter\squared}}\\ \hline
        123456 & 12 & 1234 \\ 
        12345 & 1 & 123 \\ 
        1234 & 0 & 12 \\ \hline
        \end{tabular} 
    \end{subfigure}%
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.48\linewidth}
    \rowcolors{2}{white}{gray!20}
    \centering
    \caption{Local}
    \sffamily
    \sisetup{detect-family}
        \begin{tabular}{S[table-format=6.0, table-number-alignment = right] S[table-format=2.0, table-number-alignment = right] S[table-format=4.0, table-number-alignment = right]}\hline
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Foo} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$F$ in \si{\hertz}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\sigma$ in \si{\newton\per\meter\squared}}\\ \hline
        123456 & 12 & 1234 \\ 
        12345 & 1 & 123 \\ 
        1234 & 0 & 12 \\ \hline
        \end{tabular} 
    \end{subfigure} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

**Edit**

If I just set an `{S S S}` tabular, the output would be correctly aligned, but sometimes I would like to change just one option for a single column. I think that not intuitive.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question: You *are* able to combine global options (set with `\sisetup`) and local options (set using `S[...]`), where the local options will override the global ones. Try setting `table-number-alignment = left` for the second column of the second table, for example.

Comment: @Jake Yes, that is giving no problems. But what happened to the right alignment of the first table? It seems like `S[table-format=6.0]` overrides `\sisetup{table-number-alignment = right}`. Solution: `S[table-format=6.0, table-number-alignment = right]` but thats a lot of text and not logical for my taste.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I see. This doesn't seem to be a problem with mixing global and local options, but with the order in which `table-number-alignment` and `table-format` are provided: Try swapping the order of the options in the second table, and you'll see that `table-format` deactivates the `table-number-alignment`.

Comment: OK, I can reproduce that as well. Is that a bug? Definitely not very intuitive. The first table can just be set with much more writing. A global `table-number-alignment` for a table or document is not possible.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi This is documented: `table-format` sets `table-number-alignment = center`, so any other alignment _has_ to be given after `table-format`.

Comment: Sorry, haven't seen that in your documentation. Well, than I do a feature request here: I think, that should be changed as overwriting other options always confuses. Thx for all your effort and (by the way) my favourite package!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting `table-format` automatically sets `table-number-alignment = center`, as covered in the package documentation. Thus if you set `table-format` and want a different alignment you need to set it as well.

The reason for this is that 'out of the box' the settings include `table-number-alignment = center-decimal-marker` (as this is the 'safe' position). Thus without this auto-setting behaviour, you would see no change at all by setting `table-format` alone, which would be pretty confusing.