# Siunitx: how to deal with invalid numerical input '-'?

Tags: errors, color, siunitx

Thanks to you all, I found `siunitx` for decimal alignment. However, some of the columns in my correlation matrix don't have any numbers and have "-" instead. siunitx gives me an error about invalid numerical input. How can I get around this?

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[6pt]{article}
\usepackage[landscape, total={8.5in, 5.45in}, top=1.5in, bottom=1.25in, right=1.
25in, left=1.25in, centering]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[default]{cantarell}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array}
\definecolor{tableShade8}{HTML}{78C679}
\definecolor{tableShade9}{HTML}{ADDD8E}
\definecolor{tableShade10}{HTML}{D7E9C0}
\definecolor{tableShade7}{HTML}{F7FCB9}
\definecolor{tableShade2}{HTML}{F1F5FA}
\definecolor{tableShade3}{HTML}{dddddd}

\pagestyle{empty}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\arrayrulecolor{tableShade3}

% this is the column for rotated headers
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\begin{turn}{90}\begin{minipage}{#1}\footnotesize}l%
<{\end{minipage}\end{turn}}%
}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\textbf{Tricky longtable with rotated headers for a correlation matrix}\end{center}
\setlength\LTleft{0in}
\setlength\LTright{0in}
\setlength\LTpre{-0.3cm}
\setlength\LTpost{0in}
\rowcolors{1}{tableShade2}{white}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{8pt}
\centering

\begin{longtable}{lS[table-format=+1.2]
               S[table-format=+1.2]
               S[table-format=+1.2]
               S[table-format=+1.2]
               S[table-format=+1.2]
               S[table-format=+1.2]
               S[table-format=+1.2]
               S[table-format=+1.2]
               S[table-format=+1.2]
               S[table-format=+1.2]
               S[table-format=+1.2]
               S[table-format=+1.2]}

\hiderowcolors
&&\multicolumn{7}{c}{First Group}&\multicolumn{4}{c}{Second Group}\\\cmidrule(lr){3-9}\cmidrule(lr){10-13}
&\multicolumn{1}{R{2.4cm}}{A long heading}
&\multicolumn{1}{R{2.4cm}}{Another \\ long heading}
&\multicolumn{1}{R{2.4cm}}{Third super long \\long heading}
&\multicolumn{1}{R{2.4cm}}{Fourth heading}
&\multicolumn{1}{R{2.4cm}}{Fifth blah\\loooooong blah}
&\multicolumn{1}{R{2.4cm}}{And another \\ heading}
&\multicolumn{1}{R{2.4cm}}{As if that \\ was not enough}
&\multicolumn{1}{R{2.4cm}}{And so it \\ keeps on going}
&\multicolumn{1}{R{2.4cm}}{When exactly \\ will this end?}
&\multicolumn{1}{R{2.4cm}}{Not exactly \\minimal is it?}
&\multicolumn{1}{R{2.4cm}}{Welcome to my\\ longtable hell}
&\multicolumn{1}{R{2.4cm}}{And this is it\\ I promise}\\
\specialrule{0.01em}{0.0em}{0em}
\endhead
\specialrule{0.01em}{0.0em}{0em}
\noalign{\raggedright
\footnotesize
%Complicated legend begins
\begin{tabular}{llllllllll}
\addlinespace[0.2em]
\hiderowcolors
\multicolumn{6}{l}{\textbf{LEGEND}}\\
{\cellcolor{tableShade8}$\ge$0.8}&:Very high&
{\cellcolor{tableShade9}0.60-0.79}&:High&
{\cellcolor{tableShade10}0.40-0.59}&:Moderate&
{\cellcolor{tableShade7}0.20-0.39}&:Low&
{\cellcolor{tableShade2}$\le$0.19}&:Very low\\
\end{tabular}
}

\endfoot

\multicolumn{13}{l}{\textbf{A subheading for the data}}\\\hline
\showrowcolors
First variable&{\cellcolor{tableShade8}1}&{\cellcolor{tableShade9}-0.72}&{\cellcolor{tableShade2}0.07}&{\cellcolor{tableShade2}0.08}&{\cellcolor{tableShade2}0.04}&{\cellcolor{tableShade2}-0.05}&{\cellcolor{tableShade2}0.14}&{\cellcolor{tableShade2}-0.16}&{\cellcolor{tableShade2}0.13}&{\cellcolor{tableShade2}-0.05}&{\cellcolor{tableShade10}0.58}&{\cellcolor{tableShade10}0.55}\\

Second variable &{\cellcolor{tableShade9}-0.72}&{\cellcolor{tableShade8}1}&{\cellcolor{tableShade2}-0.07}&{\cellcolor{tableShade2}-0.07}&{\cellcolor{tableShade2}-0.01}&{\cellcolor{tableShade2}0.06}&{\cellcolor{tableShade2}-0.09}&{\cellcolor{tableShade2}0.1}&{\cellcolor{tableShade2}-0.09}&{\cellcolor{tableShade2}0.03}&{\cellcolor{tableShade7}-0.32}&{\cellcolor{tableShade7}-0.31}\\

Third variable &{\cellcolor{tableShade2}0.07}&{\cellcolor{tableShade2}-0.07}&{\cellcolor{tableShade8}1}&{\cellcolor{tableShade2}0.06}&{\cellcolor{tableShade2}0.06}&{\cellcolor{tableShade2}0.05}&{\cellcolor{tableShade2}0.07}&{\cellcolor{tableShade2}-0.08}&{\cellcolor{tableShade2}0.06}&{\cellcolor{tableShade2}-0.09}&{\cellcolor{tableShade2}-0.16}&{\cellcolor{tableShade2}-0.19}\\

Whoa what is this&{\cellcolor{tableShade2}0.08}&{\cellcolor{tableShade2}-0.07}&{\cellcolor{tableShade2}0.06}&{\cellcolor{tableShade8}1}&-&-&-&-&-&-&{\cellcolor{tableShade2}0.07}&{\cellcolor{tableShade2}-0.01}\\

Fourth Variable&{\cellcolor{tableShade2}0.04}&{\cellcolor{tableShade2}-0.01}&{\cellcolor{tableShade2}0.06}&-&{\cellcolor{tableShade8}1}&{\cellcolor{tableShade8}0.86}&{\cellcolor{tableShade7}-0.32}&{\cellcolor{tableShade2}-0.11}&{\cellcolor{tableShade7}-0.32}&{\cellcolor{tableShade2}-0.16}&{\cellcolor{tableShade2}0.07}&{\cellcolor{tableShade2}0.12}\\

\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, I am getting an error about the ! ! Invalid numerical input '-'. I looked at the siunitx manual and I am finding it hard to resolve this error. Any help would be most welcome! Thanks for your time.

References:

[1. Question about 'dcolumn' and `siunitx` on tex.stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44685/aligning-decimal-points-in-table)

[2. `siunitx` for bolded numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2766/siunitx-aligning-numbers-by-decimal-points-in-tables-doesnt-work-for-bolded-or)

[3. `siunitx` manual](ftp://www.ctan.org/ctan/macros/latex/exptl/siunitx/siunitx.pdf)

Comment: You are not using `siunitx` here to typeset your numbers, as they are all inside braces. To get things working properly, load the `etoolbox` package and `\robustify\cellcolor` in your preamble. Then remove all of the extra braces. You should also set `table-format = -1.2`, as with the settings you use the signs will not have any space reserved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Taking your code, removing the bad braces and adding in braces around 'non-numerical' input for the dashes leads to

```
\documentclass[6pt]{article}
\usepackage[landscape, total={8.5in, 5.45in}, top=1.5in, bottom=1.25in, right=1.
25in, left=1.25in, centering]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[default]{cantarell}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array}
\definecolor{tableShade8}{HTML}{78C679}
\definecolor{tableShade9}{HTML}{ADDD8E}
\definecolor{tableShade10}{HTML}{D7E9C0}
\definecolor{tableShade7}{HTML}{F7FCB9}
\definecolor{tableShade2}{HTML}{F1F5FA}
\definecolor{tableShade3}{HTML}{dddddd}

\pagestyle{empty}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\arrayrulecolor{tableShade3}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify\cellcolor

% this is the column for rotated headers
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\begin{turn}{90}\begin{minipage}{#1}\footnotesize}l%
<{\end{minipage}\end{turn}}%
}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\textbf{Tricky longtable with rotated headers for a correlation matrix}\end{center}
\setlength\LTleft{0in}
\setlength\LTright{0in}
\setlength\LTpre{-0.3cm}
\setlength\LTpost{0in}
\rowcolors{1}{tableShade2}{white}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{8pt}
\centering

\begin{longtable}{lS[table-format=-1.2]
               S[table-format=-1.2]
               S[table-format=-1.2]
               S[table-format=-1.2]
               S[table-format=-1.2]
               S[table-format=-1.2]
               S[table-format=-1.2]
               S[table-format=-1.2]
               S[table-format=-1.2]
               S[table-format=-1.2]
               S[table-format=-1.2]
               S[table-format=-1.2]}

\hiderowcolors
&&\multicolumn{7}{c}{First Group}&\multicolumn{4}{c}{Second Group}\\\cmidrule(lr){3-9}\cmidrule(lr){10-13}
&\multicolumn{1}{R{2.4cm}}{A long heading}
&\multicolumn{1}{R{2.4cm}}{Another \\ long heading}
&\multicolumn{1}{R{2.4cm}}{Third super long \\long heading}
&\multicolumn{1}{R{2.4cm}}{Fourth heading}
&\multicolumn{1}{R{2.4cm}}{Fifth blah\\loooooong blah}
&\multicolumn{1}{R{2.4cm}}{And another \\ heading}
&\multicolumn{1}{R{2.4cm}}{As if that \\ was not enough}
&\multicolumn{1}{R{2.4cm}}{And so it \\ keeps on going}
&\multicolumn{1}{R{2.4cm}}{When exactly \\ will this end?}
&\multicolumn{1}{R{2.4cm}}{Not exactly \\minimal is it?}
&\multicolumn{1}{R{2.4cm}}{Welcome to my\\ longtable hell}
&\multicolumn{1}{R{2.4cm}}{And this is it\\ I promise}\\
\specialrule{0.01em}{0.0em}{0em}
\endhead
\specialrule{0.01em}{0.0em}{0em}
\noalign{\raggedright
\footnotesize
%Complicated legend begins
\begin{tabular}{llllllllll}
\addlinespace[0.2em]
\hiderowcolors
\multicolumn{6}{l}{\textbf{LEGEND}}\\
{\cellcolor{tableShade8}$\ge$0.8}&:Very high&
{\cellcolor{tableShade9}0.60--0.79}&:High&
{\cellcolor{tableShade10}0.40--0.59}&:Moderate&
{\cellcolor{tableShade7}0.20--0.39}&:Low&
{\cellcolor{tableShade2}$\le$0.19}&:Very low\\
\end{tabular}
}

\endfoot

\multicolumn{13}{l}{\textbf{A subheading for the data}}\\\hline
\showrowcolors
First variable&\cellcolor{tableShade8}1&\cellcolor{tableShade9}-0.72&\cellcolor{tableShade2}0.07&\cellcolor{tableShade2}0.08&\cellcolor{tableShade2}0.04&\cellcolor{tableShade2}-0.05&\cellcolor{tableShade2}0.14&\cellcolor{tableShade2}-0.16&\cellcolor{tableShade2}0.13&\cellcolor{tableShade2}-0.05&\cellcolor{tableShade10}0.58&\cellcolor{tableShade10}0.55\\

Second variable &\cellcolor{tableShade9}-0.72&\cellcolor{tableShade8}1&\cellcolor{tableShade2}-0.07&\cellcolor{tableShade2}-0.07&\cellcolor{tableShade2}-0.01&\cellcolor{tableShade2}0.06&\cellcolor{tableShade2}-0.09&\cellcolor{tableShade2}0.1&\cellcolor{tableShade2}-0.09&\cellcolor{tableShade2}0.03&\cellcolor{tableShade7}-0.32&\cellcolor{tableShade7}-0.31\\

Third variable &\cellcolor{tableShade2}0.07&\cellcolor{tableShade2}-0.07&\cellcolor{tableShade8}1&\cellcolor{tableShade2}0.06&\cellcolor{tableShade2}0.06&\cellcolor{tableShade2}0.05&\cellcolor{tableShade2}0.07&\cellcolor{tableShade2}-0.08&\cellcolor{tableShade2}0.06&\cellcolor{tableShade2}-0.09&\cellcolor{tableShade2}-0.16&\cellcolor{tableShade2}-0.19\\

Whoa what is this&\cellcolor{tableShade2}0.08&\cellcolor{tableShade2}-0.07&\cellcolor{tableShade2}0.06&\cellcolor{tableShade8}1
&{--}&{--}&{--}&{--}&{--}&{--}&\cellcolor{tableShade2}0.07&\cellcolor{tableShade2}-0.01\\

Fourth Variable&\cellcolor{tableShade2}0.04&\cellcolor{tableShade2}-0.01&\cellcolor{tableShade2}0.06
&{--}&\cellcolor{tableShade8}1&\cellcolor{tableShade8}0.86&\cellcolor{tableShade7}-0.32&\cellcolor{tableShade2}-0.11&\cellcolor{tableShade7}-0.32&\cellcolor{tableShade2}-0.16&\cellcolor{tableShade2}0.07&\cellcolor{tableShade2}0.12\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

This will correctly align the decimals, and retains the cell colouration. Note that it is necessary to make `\cellcolor` 'engine robust' for this to work.

Comment: Thanks very much! It looks great now, but the numbers are in a different font. Is that intentional?

Comment: See the manual on font settings. You probably want to set `mode = text, detect-all`.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think they are really minus signs, but just a place holder? If I change your table to use

```
&\textemdash&
```

instead of

```
 &-&
```

in all places, it works for me.

Comment: This works as well! Thanks for the alternative! Any thoughts on how to make the real minus sign behave with the decimal alignment? I thought the + before 1.2 in `table-format=+1.2` took care of it... but apparently, that isn't helping.