# alignment problem with bold (negative) numbers

Tags: tables, align, bold

I am trying to create a table containing a correlation matrix. I marked the significant numbers bold and insignificant are just normal. Anyhow, all boldifyed numbers are aligned differently than the "normal" ones. I tried to put the content in
    multicolumn{1}{c}[}
But even then the numbers are not "correctly" aligned. Is there a way to fix that? Additionally, I tried to put a star after the significant numbers but the star is like a "multiplying" star (centered and not "exponent").

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=4cm, right=3cm, top=3cm, bottom=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage[labelsep=newline,% line break after label
   justification=raggedright,
   singlelinecheck=off,
   font=sc]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp!]
\setlength\tabcolsep{0.1pt}  % default value: 6.0pt

\caption{Pearson and Spearman Rank Correlation Matrix}
\label{tab:PSCorrelation}
\scriptsize
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}%
  { @{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{11}{d{2.3}} }
\toprule
 & \mc{(1)} & \mc{(2)} & \mc{(3)} & \mc{(4)} & \mc{(5)} & \mc{(6)} & \mc{(7)} & \mc{(8)} & \mc{(9)} & \mc{(10)} & \mc{(11)} \\ [0.5ex]
\midrule
(1) (D)SUE1
 & & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.877} & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.257} & -0.005 & \textbf{$-$0.095} & \textbf{$-$0.101} & \textbf{$-$0.093} & 0.000 & \textbf{$-$0.061} & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.089} & -0.001 \\
(2) (D)SUE2
 & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.858} &  & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.286} & -0.008 & \textbf{$-$0.093} & \textbf{$-$0.101} & \textbf{$-$0.088} & -0.004 & \textbf{$-$0.062} & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.095} & -0.005 \\
(3) (D)SUE3
 & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.256} & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.295} &  & 0.010 & 0.008 & \textbf{$-$0.144} & \textbf{$-$0.076} & 0.006 & \textbf{$-$0.043} & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.165} & \textbf{$-$0.083} \\
(4) $\Delta$SPOT
 & -0.011 & \textbf{$-$0.023} & -0.009 &  & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.177} & \textbf{$-$0.126} & \textbf{$-$0.160} & -0.000 & 0.017 & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.023} & \textbf{$-$0.253} \\
(5) $\Delta$SLOPE
 & \textbf{$-$0.031} & \textbf{$-$0.024} & 0.013 & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.274} &  & -0.006 & -0.004 & 0.016 & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.081} & \textbf{$-$0.028} & \textbf{$-$0.086} \\
(6) $\Delta$LEVERAGE
 & \textbf{$-$0.106} & \textbf{$-$0.102} & \textbf{$-$0.110} & \textbf{$-$0.163} & \textbf{$-$0.051} &  & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.259} & 0.006 & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.030} & \textbf{$-$0.094} & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.101} \\
(7) $\Delta$VOLA
 & \textbf{$-$0.123} & \textbf{$-$0.119} & \textbf{$-$0.036} & \textbf{$-$0.230} & \textbf{$-$0.079} & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.316} &  & 0.010 & -0.011 & \textbf{$-$0.051} & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.195} \\
(8) UPGRADE
 & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.022} & 0.015 & 0.004 & -0.002 & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.024} & 0.011 & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.024} &  & \textbf{$-$0.029} & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.018} & \textbf{$-$0.018} \\
(9) DOWNGRADE
 & \textbf{$-$0.057} & \textbf{$-$0.053} & \textbf{$-$0.035} & 0.009 & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.064} & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.048} & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.033} & \textbf{$-$0.022} &  & \textbf{$-$0.024} & 0.000 \\
(10) BHAR
 & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.073} & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.067} & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.155} & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.037} & 0.007 & \textbf{$-$0.065} & \textbf{$-$0.095} & 0.015 & -0.016 &  & \textbf{$-$0.207} \\
(11) CASC
 & -0.011 & -0.004 & \textbf{$-$0.030} & \textbf{$-$0.111} & \textbf{$-$0.047} & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.071} & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.099} & 0.002 & 0.008 & \textbf{$-$0.340} &  \\ [1ex]
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\begin{tablenotes}
\item[a] A subtable-specific footnote
\end{tablenotes}

\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htp!]
\setlength\tabcolsep{0.1pt}  % default value: 6.0pt

\caption{Pearson and Spearman Rank Correlation Matrix}
\label{tab:PSCorrelation}
\scriptsize
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}%
  { @{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{11}{d{2.3}} }
\toprule
 & \mc{(1)} & \mc{(2)} & \mc{(3)} & \mc{(4)} & \mc{(5)} & \mc{(6)} & \mc{(7)} & \mc{(8)} & \mc{(9)} & \mc{(10)} & \mc{(11)} \\ [0.5ex]
\midrule
(1) (D)SUE1
 & & \mc{\textbf{\hphantom{-}0.877}} & \mc{\textbf{\hphantom{-}0.257}} & -0.005 & \mc{\textbf{$-$0.095}} & \mc{\textbf{$-$0.101}} & \mc{\textbf{$-$0.093}} & 0.000 & \mc{\textbf{$-$0.061}} & \mc{\textbf{\hphantom{-}0.089}} & -0.001 \\
(2) (D)SUE2
 & \mc{\textbf{\hphantom{-}0.858}} &  & \mc{\textbf{\hphantom{-}0.286}} & -0.008 & \mc{\textbf{$-$0.093}} & \mc{\textbf{$-$0.101}} & \mc{\textbf{$-$0.088}} & -0.004 & \mc{\textbf{$-$0.062}} & \mc{\textbf{\hphantom{-}0.095}} & -0.005 \\
(3) (D)SUE3
 & \mc{\textbf{\hphantom{-}0.256}} & \mc{\textbf{\hphantom{-}0.295}} &  & 0.010 & 0.008 & \mc{\textbf{$-$0.144}} & \mc{\textbf{$-$0.076}} & 0.006 & \mc{\textbf{$-$0.043}} & \mc{\textbf{\hphantom{-}0.165}} & \mc{\textbf{$-$0.083}} \\
(4) $\Delta$SPOT
 & -0.011 & \mc{\textbf{$-$0.023}} & -0.009 &  & \mc{\textbf{\hphantom{-}0.177}} & \mc{\textbf{$-$0.126}} & \mc{\textbf{$-$0.160}} & -0.000 & 0.017 & \mc{\textbf{\hphantom{-}0.023}} & \mc{\textbf{$-$0.253}} \\
(5) $\Delta$SLOPE
 & \mc{\textbf{$-$0.031}} & \mc{\textbf{$-$0.024}} & 0.013 & \mc{\textbf{\hphantom{-}0.274}} &  & -0.006 & -0.004 & 0.016 & \mc{\textbf{\hphantom{-}0.081}} & \mc{\textbf{$-$0.028}} & \mc{\textbf{$-$0.086}} \\
(6) $\Delta$LEVERAGE
 & \mc{\textbf{$-$0.106}} & \mc{\textbf{$-$0.102}} & \mc{\textbf{$-$0.110}} & \mc{\textbf{$-$0.163}} & \mc{\textbf{$-$0.051}} &  & \mc{\textbf{\hphantom{-}0.259}} & 0.006 & \mc{\textbf{\hphantom{-}0.030}} & \mc{\textbf{$-$0.094}} & \mc{\textbf{\hphantom{-}0.101}} \\
(7) $\Delta$VOLA
 & \mc{\textbf{$-$0.123}} & \mc{\textbf{$-$0.119}} & \mc{\textbf{$-$0.036}} & \mc{\textbf{$-$0.230}} & \mc{\textbf{$-$0.079}} & \mc{\textbf{\hphantom{-}0.316}} &  & 0.010 & -0.011 & \mc{\textbf{$-$0.051}} & \mc{\textbf{\hphantom{-}0.195}} \\
(8) UPGRADE
 & \mc{\textbf{\hphantom{-}0.022}} & 0.015 & 0.004 & -0.002 & \mc{\textbf{\hphantom{-}0.024}} & 0.011 & \mc{\textbf{\hphantom{-}0.024}} &  & \mc{\textbf{$-$0.029}} & \mc{\textbf{\hphantom{-}0.018}} & \mc{\textbf{$-$0.018}} \\
(9) DOWNGRADE
 & \mc{\textbf{$-$0.057}} & \mc{\textbf{$-$0.053}} & \mc{\textbf{$-$0.035}} & 0.009 & \mc{\textbf{\hphantom{-}0.064}} & \mc{\textbf{\hphantom{-}0.048}} & \mc{\textbf{\hphantom{-}0.033}} & \mc{\textbf{$-$0.022}} &  & \mc{\textbf{$-$0.024}} & 0.000 \\
(10) BHAR
 & \mc{\textbf{\hphantom{-}0.073}} & \mc{\textbf{\hphantom{-}0.067}} & \mc{\textbf{\hphantom{-}0.155}} & \mc{\textbf{\hphantom{-}0.037}} & 0.007 & \mc{\textbf{$-$0.065}} & \mc{\textbf{$-$0.095}} & 0.015 & -0.016 &  & \mc{\textbf{$-$0.207}} \\
(11) CASC
 & -0.011 & -0.004 & \mc{\textbf{$-$0.030}} & \mc{\textbf{$-$0.111}} & \mc{\textbf{$-$0.047}} & \mc{\textbf{\hphantom{-}0.071}} & \mc{\textbf{\hphantom{-}0.099}} & 0.002 & 0.008 & \mc{\textbf{$-$0.340}} &  \\ [1ex]
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\begin{tablenotes}
\item[a] A subtable-specific footnote
\end{tablenotes}

\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: I have also tried the siunitx package, but the result is the same.

```
\begin{table}[htp!]
\sisetup{group-separator={}}
\caption{Pearson and Spearman Rank Correlation Matrix}
\begin{threeparttable}
\scriptsize
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}
{
   @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
   l
   *{12]}{S[table-format=-1.3]}
   @{}
  }
/toprule
& {(1)} & {(2)} & {(3} & {(4)} & {(5)} & {(6)} & {(7)} & {(8)} & {(9)} & & {(10)} & {(11)}\\
\midrule
(1) (D)SUE1
 & & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.877} & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.257} & -0.005 & \textbf{$-$0.095} & \textbf{$-$0.101} & \textbf{$-$0.093} & 0.000 & \textbf{$-$0.061} & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.089} & -0.001 \\
(2) (D)SUE2
 & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.858} &  & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.286} & -0.008 & \textbf{$-$0.093} & \textbf{$-$0.101} & \textbf{$-$0.088} & -0.004 & \textbf{$-$0.062} & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.095} & -0.005 \\
(3) (D)SUE3
 & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.256} & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.295} &  & 0.010 & 0.008 & \textbf{$-$0.144} & \textbf{$-$0.076} & 0.006 & \textbf{$-$0.043} & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.165} & \textbf{$-$0.083} \\
(4) $\Delta$SPOT
 & -0.011 & \textbf{$-$0.023} & -0.009 &  & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.177} & \textbf{$-$0.126} & \textbf{$-$0.160} & -0.000 & 0.017 & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.023} & \textbf{$-$0.253} \\
(5) $\Delta$SLOPE
 & \textbf{$-$0.031} & \textbf{$-$0.024} & 0.013 & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.274} &  & -0.006 & -0.004 & 0.016 & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.081} & \textbf{$-$0.028} & \textbf{$-$0.086} \\
(6) $\Delta$LEVERAGE
 & \textbf{$-$0.106} & \textbf{$-$0.102} & \textbf{$-$0.110} & \textbf{$-$0.163} & \textbf{$-$0.051} &  & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.259} & 0.006 & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.030} & \textbf{$-$0.094} & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.101} \\
(7) $\Delta$VOLA
 & \textbf{$-$0.123} & \textbf{$-$0.119} & \textbf{$-$0.036} & \textbf{$-$0.230} & \textbf{$-$0.079} & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.316} &  & 0.010 & -0.011 & \textbf{$-$0.051} & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.195} \\
(8) UPGRADE
 & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.022} & 0.015 & 0.004 & -0.002 & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.024} & 0.011 & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.024} &  & \textbf{$-$0.029} & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.018} & \textbf{$-$0.018} \\
(9) DOWNGRADE
 & \textbf{$-$0.057} & \textbf{$-$0.053} & \textbf{$-$0.035} & 0.009 & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.064} & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.048} & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.033} & \textbf{$-$0.022} &  & \textbf{$-$0.024} & 0.000 \\
(10) BHAR
 & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.073} & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.067} & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.155} & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.037} & 0.007 & \textbf{$-$0.065} & \textbf{$-$0.095} & 0.015 & -0.016 &  & \textbf{$-$0.207} \\
(11) CASC
 & -0.011 & -0.004 & \textbf{$-$0.030} & \textbf{$-$0.111} & \textbf{$-$0.047} & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.071} & \textbf{\hphantom{-}0.099} & 0.002 & 0.008 & \textbf{$-$0.340} &  \\ [1ex]
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[a] A subtable-specific footnote

\end{tablenotes}

\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
```

The columns are not "shifted" anymore, but still not properly aligned.

edit2: I tried the solution from [siunitx: aligning numbers by decimal points in tables doesn't work for bolded or italicized numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2766/siunitx-aligning-numbers-by-decimal-points-in-tables-doesnt-work-for-bolded-or), but it does not change anything.

edit3: I have found the solution for my question; I added

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify\bfseries \sisetup{
detect-weight = true , locale = DE , }

\robustify\bfseries
```

in the table environment which aligns the numeric values in the table created with siunitx correctly. Still I do not have a solution for the table created with the dcolumn package.

Comment: the crux of this problem is that computer modern bold fonts are by default "extended" (bx) rather than simply bold (b), so a "bx" digit is wider than a "b" digit. (all digits in the same font have the same width.) what is needed is to use the "b" font in tables. further, only one size of the "b" font (cmb10) is provided, and all others are scaled from that; cmr, on the other hand, has individually defined metrics for several sizes, so the widths of cmr7 digits aren't necessarily going to be the same as those of 70%-scaled cmb10 digits.  (i'm assuming the default for `\scriptsize`.)

Comment: these example are definitely not _minimal_. Another way to achieve the result is to use typewriter font family and add some manual spaces when required, along with the command `\obeyspaces`. Then you can (for example) underline significant values.

Comment: The `siunitx` solution was edited into the question (and found elsewhere on-site). The `dcolumn` solution is at [Decimals in table don't align with dcolumn when bolded](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/118458). I'm voting to close as a duplicate of the `dcolumn` solution.