# How do I right-align certain cells in a (booktabs) table?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I'm very new to LaTeX, and I'm currently waist deep in my first project using it.

I'm trying to right align some text in cells in a table. I am using booktabs, not sure if that changes anything (I'm still trying to figure out how packages work, to be honest).

[image: Here is the output]

Here is my code:

```
\begin{table}[H]
  \begin{center}
    \caption{A comparison of statistics for forest and trailside ash saplings}
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
    \toprule 
    Statistic & Forest & Trailside \\ \midrule
    \rowcolor[gray]{.9} Sample size (trees)    & 243     & 257 \\
    Mean (mm)  & 133.19 & 139.39 \\ 
    \rowcolor[gray]{.9} Median (mm)            & 93      & 100 \\ 
    Standard deviation (mm) & 110.36  & 117.96 \\ 
    \rowcolor[gray]{.9} Standard error (mm)    & 7.08   & 7.36   \\
    95\% Confidence intervals (mm) &  ~ & ~ \\
    \makebox[2.4cm][r] Upper bound & 147.07 & 153.81 \\
    \makebox[2.4cm][r] Lower bound & 119.31 & 124.96 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{table}
```

As you can see, I am currently using `\makebox[2.4][r]` to hack it in, but if there's a more elegant way to accomplish this I'd love to know it.

Comment: Welcome at tex.sx! `booktabs` is a great package, but indeed doesn't meddle with cell alignment. I also changed [tag:align] to [tag:horizontal-alignment] :-).

Comment: @lockstep is there anything I need to do to put this as resolved or something like that (I clicked the arrow next to the best answer already)? Thanks for the help!

Comment: You've done all you should -- upvoted answers you viewed as helpful, and "accepted" (that's the checkmark) the most helpful one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your table needs very little additional tweaking to achieve your objectives, I believe. In the MWE below, I use the `siunitx` package (and its column type "S") to align the numbers on the decimal point, as well as the `\multicolumn` command. Happy TeXing!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{A comparison of statistics for forest and trailside ash saplings}
\smallskip
\sisetup{table-format = 3.2}
\begin{tabular}{lSS}
\toprule 
Statistic & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Forest} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Trailside} \\ 
\midrule
\rowcolor[gray]{.9} 
Sample size (trees) & 243 & 257\\
Mean (mm)           & 133.19 & 139.39 \\ 
\rowcolor[gray]{.9} Median (mm)  & 93  & 100 \\ 
Standard deviation (mm)          & 110.36  & 117.96 \\ 
\rowcolor[gray]{.9} Standard error (mm)  & 7.08 & 7.36   \\
95\% Confidence intervals (mm) &  ~ & ~ \\
\multicolumn{1}{r}{Upper bound} & 147.07 & 153.81 \\
\multicolumn{1}{r}{Lower bound} & 119.31 & 124.96 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well I'd like to use this for the decimal point stuff, but I get a ton of errors as soon as I add `\usepackage{siunitx}`...

Comment: @Zak: The `siunitx` options have somewhat changed from version 1 to 2. Try to upgrade your TeX distribution or replace `table-format` with `tabformat`. EDIT: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2746/aligning-numbers-by-decimal-points-in-table-columns/2747#2747

Comment: @lockstep [Output](http://i.imgur.com/39euL.png), [code](http://slexy.org/raw/s2bPsZfXDh) As you can see, the "Forest" and "Trailside" headers are getting messed up. How do I exempt them from "S"?

Comment: Disregard that, that was fixed in the example up above by using `\multicolumn`.

Answer (score 9):

Using `\multicolumn` you can override the column specification for a particular cell:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
    \caption{A comparison of statistics for forest and trailside ash saplings}
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
    \toprule 
    Statistic & Forest & Trailside \\ \midrule
        \rowcolor[gray]{.9} Sample size (trees)       & 243 & 257\\
        Mean (mm)               & 133.19 & 139.39 \\ 
        \rowcolor[gray]{.9} Median (mm)   & 93   & 100\\ 
        Standard deviation (mm) & 110.36  & 117.96 \\ 
        \rowcolor[gray]{.9} Standard error (mm)    & 7.08   & 7.36\\
    95\% Confidence intervals (mm) &  ~ & ~ \\
    \multicolumn{1}{r}{Upper bound} & 147.07 & 153.81 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{r}{Lower bound} & 119.31 & 124.96 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I would also suggest you to use `\centering` instead of the `center` environment to avoid adding extra vertical spacing.

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
\multicolumn{1}{r}{Upper bound}
```

I suggest you to look at the **siunitx** package that provides an `S` column type for correctly output numerical data in tables.

Comment: egreg -- you were thinking along the same lines I did with regard to using the siunitx package (I posted before I saw your answer). :-)

Comment: @Mico Of course your answer is much more informative than mine.