# Aligning Decimal Points in Table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, punctuation, tabularx

I want to align two numbers in two different rows the decimal point.

I do see a link for that here:
[Aligning numbers by decimal points in table columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2746/aligning-numbers-by-decimal-points-in-table-columns)

However, I don't understand how to incorporate that into my code.  What follows is a reduced version of my code.

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage[font=large,labelfont=bf,tableposition=top,textfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\clearpage \newpage
\begin{table}[!ht]
\caption{Table Title}
\def\arraystretch{1.05}
\vspace{-0.2cm}
\begin{threeparttable}
\small
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l*{10}{C}}
\hline \hline \addlinespace
& (1)  \\  
Variable Name & 0.1234566  \\
& (0.1234566) \\
\hline \hline \addlinespace
 \end{tabularx}
\begin{tablenotes}
\vspace{0.1cm}
\footnotesize{

\item \noindent \hspace{-1.8mm} Notes: 

 \noindent Sources: 
 }
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 27):

In addition to trying out the [`dcolumn`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/tools) package mentioned by @DavidCarlisle, you may also want to check out some of the capabilities of the [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx) package, specifically, its `S` column type. I've simplified your (not exactly *minimal*) working example to the example code below, in order to focus on the operation of this column type:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,mathptmx,siunitx}
\sisetup{input-symbols = {()},  % do not treat "(" and ")" in any special way
         group-digits  = false} % no grouping of digits
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l S[table-format=2.7] S[table-format=4.2] @{}}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)} & \multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{(2)}  \\  
    \midrule
    Variable Name & 98.1234567 & 1234.56  \\
    & (0.6789) & (54.3)\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It may be worth nothing that `dcolumn` is included in the [`memoir`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/memoir) package.

Answer (score 24):

It looks like you don't want `tabularx` at all, just use a normal `tabular` with a `D` column for your numeric columns, perhaps defined by

```
\newcolumntype{.}{D{.}{.}{-1}}
```

using the `dcolumn` package.

for completeness, complete example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l*{2}{D{.}{.}{7}}@{}}
    \toprule
    & (1) & (2)  \\  
    \midrule
    Variable Name & 98.1234567 & 1234.56  \\
    & (0.6789) & (54.3)\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for getting back to me.  Why don't I want tabularx?  The rest of my table is designed using that, I think.  I may be wrong.  I tried changing the syntax from tabularx to tabular and it did not work.

Comment: saying "did not work" isn't very descriptive, Obviously if you switch to tabular (and it looks as if you should) you have to not use tabularx syntax, specifically the `{\textwidth}` argument and `X` columns.

Comment: @DavidCarisle.  I don't understand what you are saying.  Could you please take my code, and modify it to show what I should insert and where?  I wouldn't normally ask for this, but I do not understand a lick of what you are saying.  I am very grateful.  This might help other people coming to this thread in the future.

Comment: I've already changed your table to use tabular in your other question

Comment: @DavidCarisle.  Does that solution include having the decimals align?  Does it include making the numbers centered within the columns?  It is also not crystal clear to me what to do.  I should substitute those 4 lines with the 4 lines in your minimum working example?  I am sorry that I keep on harping about how to implement your suggestions.  I just hardly know a thing about lateX so it is difficult for me to incorporate what you are suggesting.

Comment: Answer updated with example

Comment: One problem with this solution is that all the entries (e.g. column headings) are pushed to the left of the decimal point also. For example if "(1)" is replaced with "column 1" it will be poorly aligned. Is there a way to fix/improve this?

Comment: @geordie if headings want (say) center alignment then as usual you can specify that instead of the default column alignment with `\multicolumn{1}{c}{my heading}`

Answer (score 15):

I thought I'd add my answer because it doesn't make use of any other packages (although I think using `dcolumn` is the easiest solution). What you can do is break each number column into two columns, one for the abscissa (left of the decimal) and one for the ordinate (right). Then, right align the first column, left align the second, and squeeze the space between them with `@{}`.

Specifically, this is option 1 in the question you linked.

I think the appropriate minimum solution is

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{lr@{}lr@{}l}
\hline
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{(1)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(2)}  \\  
\hline
Variable Name & 98 & .1234567 & 1234 & .56  \\
              & (0 & .6789)   &  (54 & .3)  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Almost certainly.  I've edited it appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround for when you don't have too many entries (or if you don't mind auto-substituting a piece of text into every line) is to pad with `\phantom{}` (which has the effect of taking up as much space as its argument would have taken, but will not show anything). For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{rrr}
& (1) & (2) \\  
\midrule
Variable Name & 98.1234567           & 1234.56 \\
              & (0.6789)\phantom{67} &  (54.3) \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```