# Footnotes: distance between number and text

Tags: footnotes

See this mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
    \parindent 1em%
    \noindent\hbox{\sf\bfseries\@thefnmark}\hspace*{.7em plus 0pt minus 0pt}#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  Hello\footnote{I am a footnote!}\footnote{I am another footnote}.
\end{document}
```

Which results to:

[image]

which has the distance of 0.7 em between the number and the footnote. But when I change the font to a font that has figures with proportional width, this leads to a ragged left footnote block (see below for an mwe - this does not reflect my real document, as I could simply remove the `\proportionalnums` command in the mwe):

[image]

```
% mwe with proportional figures and more footnote text
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine,blindtext}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
   \parindent 1em%
    \noindent\hbox{\proportionalnums{\@thefnmark}}\hspace*{.7em plus 0pt minus 0pt}#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Hello\footnote{I am a footnote!}\footnote{I am another footnote \blindtext}.
\end{document}
```

[image: multiline footnotes]

**Question:** how can I always make sure the begining of the footnote is at the same horizontal level (for each numbering with the same amount of digits, footnotes 1-9 have a different start level than 10-99 and 100 and above).

The solution would probably be a `\hbox to ...{..}`, the width depending on the number of digits in the footnote. I also have the situation where sometimes where I temporarily redefine `\def\thefootnote{*}` to have an `*` as a footnote symbol instead of a character. This should count as "one digit".

**Edit:** I have changed the second mwe to have more text to illustrate the multi-line footnotes

Comment: Can you add an example with a proportional width font so we can test?

Comment: Maybe use a monospaced version for the footnotemarks? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241070/align-decimal-point-proportional-font#comment573087_241070 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114331/lining-figures-in-tables-and-math-old-style-figures-in-text

Comment: @samcarter added a mwe for proportional font width.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Does this work? `\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
  \parindent 1em%
  \noindent
  \ifnum\c@footnote>9
    \hb@xt@ 20pt %
  \else
    \hb@xt@ 15pt %
  \fi
  {\sffamily\bfseries\@thefnmark\hss}#1}`

Comment: @ArashEsbati perfect! If you put this as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it. I have added a case > 99: `\ifnum\c@footnote > 99 \hb@xt@ 20pt \else` right after the `> 9` . Thank you very much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue with your code is that you put a `\hspace` after setting the `\@thefnmark`.  You can fix this by changing LaTeX's version which is:

```
\newcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
  \parindent 1em%
  \noindent
  \hb@xt@1.8em{\hss\@makefnmark}#1}
```

A more LaTeX like approach using `ifthen` package would be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine,blindtext,ifthen}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
  \parindent 1em%
  \noindent
  \ifthenelse{\value{footnote}>99}{%
    \hb@xt@ 30\p@
  }{%
    \ifthenelse{\value{footnote}<9}{%
      \hb@xt@ 10\p@
    }{%
      \hb@xt@ 20\p@
    }%
  }%
  {\sffamily\bfseries\@thefnmark\hss}#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Hello\footnote{I am a footnote!}\footnote{I am another footnote
  \blindtext}.
\addtocounter{footnote}{15}%
Hello\footnote{I am a footnote!}\footnote{I am another footnote
  \blindtext}.
\addtocounter{footnote}{99}%
Hello\footnote{I am a footnote!}\footnote{I am another footnote
  \blindtext}.
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 5):

Adjust the length to suit yourself: I used 10pt as fixed distance and 0.5em for each digit.

This assumes the footnote mark expands to a positive number, of course.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}

\usepackage{expl3}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
  \proportionalnums{\bfseries
    \makebox[\getfnmarkwidth\@thefnmark][l]{%
      \proportionalnums{\@thefnmark}%
    }%
  }%
  #1%
}
\makeatother

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Nn \getfnmarkwidth:n
 {
  \dim_eval:n { 10pt + .5em * \fp_eval:n { floor(ln(#1)/ln(10),0) + 1 } }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \getfnmarkwidth:n { V }
\cs_set_eq:NN \getfnmarkwidth \getfnmarkwidth:V
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
Hello\footnote{I am a footnote!}\footnote{I am another footnote.}

\setcounter{footnote}{9}

Hello\footnote{I am a footnote!}\footnote{I am another footnote.}
Hello\footnote{I am a footnote!}\footnote{I am another footnote.}

\setcounter{footnote}{99}
Hello\footnote{I am a footnote!}\footnote{I am another footnote.}
Hello\footnote{I am a footnote!}\footnote{I am another footnote.}

\end{document}
```

Explanation: `floor(ln(#1)/ln(10),0)+1` is the number of digits of `#1`.

[image]