# missing | in multirow

Tags: tables, multirow

missing | in 3 multirow, dont know what to do :C

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
        \hline
        Rango de Tiempo $[s]$ & Viscosidad $[\frac{cm^{2}}{s}]$\\ \hline 
        \multirow{2}{*}{$34 - 115$} & \multirow{2}{*}{$0,224t + \frac{185}{t}$ }\\  \\ \hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{$115 - 215$} & \multirow{2}{*}{$0,223t + 1,55$} \\ \\
        \hline 
        \multirow{2}{*}{> 215} & \multirow{2}{*}{$0,224t + \frac{185}{t}$ } \\\\ \hline         
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
    \end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Please post complete code rather than a mere fragment. However, in this case, it just makes no sense to use `\multirow` here as all the cells in a row are supposed to be the same height. So just get rid of the `\multirow`s as they are being misused and abused and aren't needed. (They are misused because if you use `\multirow{2}...`, then you need to leave the relevant gap in the next row of the table, which you never do.

Comment: how can i get  a "higher" row?

Comment: Better to ask questions in the question itself if at all possible.  A MWE would surely help here, but it seems that your table is simple so the suggestion by @cfr should be all you need.

Answer (score 3):

From your comments I conclude that you in fact don't want to use `\multirow` but search for a way to stretch the rows. For this there's the command `\def\arraystretch{xyx}`, e. g.:

```
\begin{table}[htb]
\def\arraystretch{1.5}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
  \hline
  Rango de Tiempo $[s]$ & Viscosidad $[\frac{cm^{2}}{s}]$ \\ \hline
  34 -- 115             & $0,224t + \frac{185}{t}$        \\ \hline
  115 -- 215            & $0,223t + 1,55$                 \\ \hline
  $> 215$               & $0,224t + \frac{185}{t}$        \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image: output 1]

However, if you want to produce tables in a considered **good style**, you definitely should `\usepackage{booktabs}`. An example use for your special case is the following:

```
\usepackage{booktabs}
…
\begin{table}[htb]
\def\arraystretch{1.5}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
  \toprule
  Rango de Tiempo $[s]$ & Viscosidad $[\frac{cm^{2}}{s}]$ \\
  \midrule
  34 -- 115             & $0,224t + \frac{185}{t}$        \\
  115 -- 215            & $0,223t + 1,55$                 \\
  $> 215$               & $0,224t + \frac{185}{t}$        \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image: output 2]

Adjusting the space between the columns can be done with e. g.

```
\begin{tabular}{c@{\hspace{.6cm}}c}
```

If you want to align cells by special symbols have a look at the [dcolumn](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/dcolumn) or the [siunitx](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package or at related questions like [2746](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2746) or [44685](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44685).

Comment: Using `@{\hspace{.6cm}}` does not affect the space between rows at all; it changes the space between the columns.

Comment: @PaulGessler My bad, I changed it.

Comment: Since the first column appears to indicate *ranges* of numbers, it's better to write -- typographically speaking -- `34--115` than `$34 - 115$`. In the former expression, `--` will generate an en-dash, whereas in the latter the `-` will generate a math-mode "minus" symbol. I don't think subtractions are intended to be performed in the first column.

Comment: @Mico I totally agree!

Answer (score 2):

Echoing @dessert's answer, I don't think you need `\multirow` at all. I would further like to suggest that (a) you provide a bit more visual structure to the header, (b) use inline-style fractions, and (c) use the macros of the siunitx package to format the units of measurement as well as the numbers that contain `,` as the decimal marker.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[per-mode=symbol,output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}
\toprule
Rango de Tiempo  & Viscosidad \\{}
[\si{\second}] & [\si{\centi\meter\squared\per\second}]\\ 
\midrule 
34--115  & $\num{0,224}t + 185/t$ \\  
115--215 & $\num{0,223}t + \num{1,55}$  \\
$>215$   & $\num{0,224}t + 185/t$ \\ 
\bottomrule         
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that a `tabular` where vertical rules are used must have *all* cells specified, either empty or not.

Your “skipped rows” are obtained by `\\ \\`, which just specifies the first cell in the row as empty. With `\\ & \\` also the second cell is specified. The code

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
Rango de Tiempo $[s]$ & Viscosidad $[\frac{cm^{2}}{s}]$\\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{$34 - 115$} & \multirow{2}{*}{$0,224t + \frac{185}{t}$ }\\ & \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{$115 - 215$} & \multirow{2}{*}{$0,223t + 1,55$} \\ & \\
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{> 215} & \multirow{2}{*}{$0,224t + \frac{185}{t}$ } \\ & \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

will produce

[image]

that, however, has several small mistakes in it.

1. Symbols for units should be upright and in parentheses, not square brackets that denote dimensions, rather than units (use in Spanish might be different, though).
2. The decimal comma should not be spaced; with `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}`, the default output of `$0.224$` would be 0,224 with no space.
3. You shouldn't use a minus sign for the interval, but an en-dash.

Here are fixes for these issues.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{bigstrut,array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\setlength{\bigstrutjot}{6pt}

\begin{tabular}{|c<{\bigstrut}|c|}
\hline
Rango de Tiempo (s) & Viscosidad (cm$^{2}$/s) \\
\hline
$34$--$115$ & $0.224t + \frac{185}{t}$ \\
\hline
$115$--$215$ & $0.223t + 1.55$ \\
\hline
$>215$ & $0.224t + \frac{185}{t}$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Finally, using `siunitx` is better (and also `booktabs`); it's necessary to disable the “quoting” mechanism of `babel-spanish` that goes into the way also in several other circumstances.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}

\sisetup{range-phrase=--,output-decimal-marker={,}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{cc}
\toprule
Rango de Tiempo (\si{s}) & Viscosidad (\si{cm^2/s}) \\
\midrule
\numrange{34}{115} & $\num{0.224}t + \frac{\num{185}}{t}$ \\
\addlinespace
\numrange{115}{215} & $\num{0.223}t + \num{1.55}$ \\
\addlinespace
\num{> 215} & $\num{0.224}t + \frac{\num{185}}{t}$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]