# ctable decimal alignment

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, siunitx, ctable

I'm trying to replicate `siunitx`'s decimal alignmnent in tables, using ctables.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ctable}
\begin{document}
\ctable[] {rc} {}{
  \FL \textbf{Data} & \textbf{Distance}
  \ML one & 1.1
  \ML ten & 10.1
  \ML hundred & 100.1
  \LL
}
\end{document}
```

which results in:

[image: this is what I get]

And I'm looking to get somethign that looks closer to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2746/aligning-numbers-by-decimal-points-in-table-columns).

Comment: Without `siunitx`? Why?

Comment: ctable just uses tabular internally so you could use siunitx or dcolumn to do the decimal alignment as in a normal tabular.

Comment: I (mistakenly) assumed that one had to use `tabular` to get `siunitx` to work.  All the examples I had seen used `tabular` only, and a cursory search didn't give me any results.

@DavidCarlisle, feel free to answer the question and I'll accept it.

Comment: @egreg presumably the OP prefers the interface of `ctable` compared to the 'regular' `tabular` code...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`ctable` just uses `tabular` internally so you could use `siunitx` or `dcolumn` to do the decimal alignment as in a normal `tabular`.

```
\ctable[] {rS} {
  }{
  \FL \textbf{Data} & \textbf{Distance}
  \ML one & 1.1
  \ML ten & 10.1
  \ML hundred & 100.1
  \LL
}
```

[image]