# Problem with aligning numbers with brackets surrounding them

Tags: tables, siunitx

english is not my native language, but I will try to explain my question the best way I can.

My problem is the extra spacing between the L and T column which apparently comes when I write the numbers in scientific mode. Is there any way to have scientific numbers like this, align them on comma, and make the spacing in columns more normal (smaller) ?

Preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\sisetup{input-symbols = ()}
```

Table code:

```
\begin{table}[ht]\centering
\caption[caption]{caption}\label{reg_basis1}
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\sisetup{table-space-text-post = \sym{***}}

\begin{tabular}{l*{5}{S[table-align-text-post=false]}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{L}}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{T}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{n}}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\(R^{2}\)}}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Justert $R^{2}$}}\\
\midrule
1997 - 2008 & 0.207 \sym{***} & 3.5\num{1e-4} \sym{***} & {623} & 0.27 & 0.21  \\
            & (0.049)         & (0.8\num{1e-4})         &       &      &       \\
        \addlinespace
2009 - 2015 &&&&&  \\
            &&&&&  \\
        \addlinespace
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize Estimerte standardavvik er gitt i parenteser}\\
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} $p<0.05$, \sym{**} $p<0.01$, \sym{***} \  $p<0.001$}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I hope anyone here has time to answer me. I have tried searching/googling, but I haven't found anything specific which I can use to solve my problem.

Comment: Erh, leave the formatting to the SE column, don't use `\num` in the column, `3.5e-4` is enough, the rest is configuration of the column. You probably also want 5 separate S columns not 5 of the same configuration

Comment: Hopefully you don't mind that I have changed the title of your question. Now it shows the _real_ problem and which is unique so far in the questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your main problem are the *(round) brackets* used to surround your numbers, because they are also used as natural input of the `\num` command to indicate the error of a number. That is why you have to protect the (round) brackets by putting them into curly brackets.

(I wouldn't use your solution and add them to the `input-symbols`, because that could cause some undesired side effects, which I haven't tested for.)

To then get the spacing right is pretty straight forward and is already answered for example [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2747/95441) providing the "elements" which could be found in the column to the options of the `S` specifier like `table-format`. (Have a look at [table 25 of the `siunitx` manual v2.6 on page 47](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.pdf#page=47)).

Have a look at the following code which I reduced a little bit, to not distract from the main tabular.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
        \def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
        \sisetup{
            table-align-text-post=false,
        }
    \begin{tabular}{
        l
        S[table-format=1.3,   table-space-text-pre={(},table-space-text-post={\sym{***}}]
        S[table-format=1.1e-1,table-space-text-pre={(},table-space-text-post={\sym{***}}]
        S[table-format=3]
        S[table-format=1.2]
        S[table-format=1.2]
        }
            \toprule
                      & {\textbf{L}}    & {\textbf{T}}   & {\textbf{n}}
                                                               & {\textbf{$R^{2}$}}
                                                                      & {\textbf{Justert $R^{2}$}} \\
            \midrule
        1997 -- 2008  & 0.207 \sym{***} & 3e-4 \sym{***} & 623 & 0.27 & 0.21 \\
                      & {(}0.049{)}     & {(}0.8e-4{)}   &     &      &      \\
                \addlinespace
        2009 -- 2015  &                 &                &     &      &      \\
                      &                 &                &     &      &      \\
                \addlinespace
            \bottomrule
        \multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize Estimerte standardavvik er gitt i parenteser}\\
        \multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize
            \sym{*}   $p < \num{0.05}$,
            \sym{**}  $p < \num{0.01}$,
            \sym{***} $p < \num{0.001}$}\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm kind of a newbie at LaTeX and tables, and you probably saw that from my code. But this was really helpful. To be honest, I don't understand everything you did here, but I'll look into it more. Thank you very much again for your time :)

Comment: You are welcome. Have a look at my edited answer. Hopefully then and latest having a look at the suggested table of the manual and having a look at the following examples given there will help you to understand. If this shouldn't be sufficient, please feel free to ask again here in the comment.  If you like my answer then you can -- besides accepting it -- upvote it by hitting the uparrow above the accepted mark.

Comment: Thanks again. I'll have a look at the manual. I upvoted your answer :)