# Hline length not filling width of the table

Tags: tables, hhline

I used `siunitx` package to align numbers as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2747/152005).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\title{Test}
\date{August 2018}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{tabular}{rS[table-format=8.2]}
\hline 
True sigma used & \ 9.117647 \\
True pixel value & 67.000000 \\
\hline
Pixel Value & 67.025372 \\
Error & \ 0.025372 \\
Squared Error & \ 0.000643 \\
Predicted Sigma & \ 8.787887 \\
Iteration Number & \text{87/100} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

However, the `\hline`s do not go well with this I guess:

[image]

How do I fix this? Also, how do center align `87/100` or anything that's not a number?

---

Update : After @egreg 's comment, I noticed that changing `table-format=8.2` to `table-format=8.6` or `table-format=x.6` (telling it to expect 6 digits after the decimal and x before it), hline alignment is gone :) Thanks.

[image]

I still have centering the text issue :/

Comment: Could you please add a compilable MWE?

Comment: Well, you're asking to reserve space for three digits in the integral part and two for the fractional part, but then use six for the latter.

Comment: @sporc updated the code

Comment: If you want the text to be centered just change `r` to `c`: `\begin{tabular}{cS[table-format=8.2]}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can center align the column by inserting a `\multicolumn` command.

Changing the format specifier to `table-format=8.6` resolves the problem with the `hline` lenght:

[image: Table with correct hline]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\title{Test}
\date{August 2018}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{tabular}{rS[table-format=8.6]}
\hline 
True sigma used & 9.117647 \\
True pixel value & 67.000000 \\
\hline
Pixel Value & 67.025372 \\
Error & 0.025372 \\
Squared Error & 0.000643 \\
Predicted Sigma & 8.787887 \\
Iteration Number &  {87/100} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

### Better spacing

Changing the format specifier to `table-format=2.6` removes unnecessary white space. Adding `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}` adds some more spacing between the row of the table:

[image: table with better spacing]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

% for spacing in the table
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}

\begin{tabular}{rS[table-format=2.6]}
\hline 
True sigma used & 9.117647 \\
True pixel value & 67.000000 \\
\hline
Pixel Value & 67.025372 \\
Error & 0.025372 \\
Squared Error & 0.000643 \\
Predicted Sigma & 8.787887 \\
Iteration Number & {87/100} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why using `8.6`? `2.6` should be enough. You get a lot of unnecessary white space

Comment: @sporc In a heat wave, Tom likes white space resembling an area covered with snow. ;-)

Comment: I did not want to change more than neccessary. Sure, it may not look very nice. But then, I also think that the line spacing is not 'nice' and I didn't change it either. But I can change it.

Answer (score 4):

With `table-format=8.2` you reserve space for 8 digits before the dot and 2 after the dot, you need to change it to `table-format=2.8`, but for your given numbers `2.6` is enough

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\title{Test}
\date{August 2018}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{tabular}{rS[table-format=2.6]}
\hline 
True sigma used & \ 9.117647 \\
True pixel value & 67.000000 \\
\hline
Pixel Value & 67.025372 \\
Error & \ 0.025372 \\
Squared Error & \ 0.000643 \\
Predicted Sigma & \ 8.787887 \\
Iteration Number & \text{87/100} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]