# Alignment of a table around decimal point

Tags: siunitx, arrays

I have the following code in latex

```
{\begin{array}{c|c}
integer&real\\\hline
1&114.12382811\\
2&64.284747272\\
3&0.000267356293929\\
4&273912624.91\\
\vdots&\vdots\\
\end{array}
}
```

I am wanting to form a table with headers and division lines but the numbers in the right hand column need to be aligned on the decimal point, I know this can be done (it can be seen here [Aligning numbers by decimal points in table columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2746/aligning-numbers-by-decimal-points-in-table-columns) ) however I am unsure of how to combine this with the table I want to produce. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the  `S` columntype, from `siunitx` for that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, siunitx}

\begin{document}

\[ \begin{array}{c|S[table-format =9.15, table-number-alignment=center]}
\text{integer} & {\text{real}} \\
\hline
1&114.12382811\\
2&64.284747272\\
3&0.000267356293929\\
4&273912624.91\\
\vdots&{\vdots} \\
\end{array} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]