# Table Formatting using siunitx

Tags: tables, siunitx

I am trying to make a table with four columns: three of the columns are to be center aligned, and one is to be aligned by decimal places ( using `S[table-format=3.2]`). Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c c S[table-format=3.2] c}
\toprule
\multicolumn{4}{c}{SI Prefixes} \\
%\hline \hline
\midrule \midrule
Prefix & Symbol & Multiplication Factor & $\ldots$ in Scientific Notation \\
\midrule
giga & G & 1000000000 & $10^9$ \\
mega & M & 1000000 & $10^6$ \\ 
kilo & k & 1000 & $10^3$ \\
deca & D & 10 & $10^1$ \\
\rowcolor{gray!20} - & - & 1 & $10^0$ \\
deci & d & 0.1 & $10^{-1}$ \\
centi & c & 0.01 & $10^{-2}$ \\
milli & m & 0.001 & $10^{-3}$ \\
micro & $\mu$ & 0.000001 & $10^{-6}$ \\
nano & n & 0.000000001 & $10^{-9}$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

However, here is my result:

[image]

The columns are overlapping, and I cannot figure out how to fix it. I can't think of a way to set the width of the third column, as that would fix the issue, but to my understanding, you can only fix the width by doing something like `p{5cm}`; the `S` type will not allow that.

Comment: you need `{...}` around the heading so it isn't parsed as a number  but main issue is you have specified a format of 3.2 so 2 decimal places but your numbers are 0.000000001 which have rather more than 2 digits after the point. Use a format that matches your data

Comment: How would I format it then? Sorry, I've never used ```siunitx``` before. The max amount of digits is 9, so would I put 3.9?

Comment: It just hit me, the number left of . is the number of digits left of the decimal and same with the right. So I should put 10.9.

Comment: Slightly off-topic: The shortened form of `\deca` (`\deka` works too...) is `da`, not `D`.

Comment: Good point... I was not aware of this

Comment: Two years late and slightly off-topic but I think you might want to include hecto- (h) 100

Comment: Still later: I think, in the line concerning the "micro" Prefix: the `\mu` should be printed in upright font, I guess?  At least, it looks strange to see an italic `\mu` while the rest of the prefix symbols are upright.

Comment: Just curious: Would it be possible, to prepare the table contents by using `siunitx` capabilities, to use the same input in the second til fourth column, while `siunitx` prints either the symbol, the number or the scientic repesentation of the number.  So first line would read in the input as `Giga & \giga & \giga & \giga \\`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*Update, March 2022*: I wrote the answer shown below in early 2019, when version 2.xx of the `siunitx` package still roamed the earth. If you wish to compile the answer code under version 3.xx of the `siunitx` package, I suggest you load the `siunitx` package with the option `v2=`, i.e., as `\usepackage{siunitx}[=v2]`. Please see [How to convert the macro `\si` in the new version 3 of siunitx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/614113/5001) for additional details.

---

As David Carlisle has already pointed out in a comment, you must (a) change `S[table-format=3.2]` to `S[table-format=10.9]` and (b) encase the string `Multiplication Factor` in curly braces, to keep it from being interpreted by `siunitx`.

In addition, you may want to (c) write `\si{\micro}` instead of `$\mu$` in the second column. The text-mu and math-mu glyphs look quite different in most fonts. Finally, since you're using the `siunitx` package, why not (d) use the `S` column type for the final column as well and input `e9` thru `e-9` instead of the more cumbersome `$10^9$` thru `$10^{-9}$`?

A separate observation: the standard short form of `deca` (or `deka`) is `da`, not `D`. For sure, both `\si{\deca}` and `\si{\deka}` produce `da`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{l c S[table-format=10.9] S[retain-zero-exponent=true]}
\toprule
\multicolumn{4}{c}{SI Prefixes} \\
\addlinespace %\midrule
Prefix & Symbol & {Multiplication Factor} & {\dots\ in Scientific Notation} \\
\midrule
giga  & \si{\giga} & 1000000000 & e9 \\
mega  & \si{\mega} & 1000000    & e6 \\ 
kilo  & \si{\kilo} & 1000       & e3 \\
deca  & \si{\deca} & 10         & e1 \\ % "\deka" works too
\rowcolor{gray!20}  -- & -- & 1 & e0 \\
deci  & \si{\deci} & 0.1        & e-1 \\
centi & \si{\centi}& 0.01       & e-2 \\
milli & \si{\milli}& 0.001      & e-3 \\
micro & \si{\micro}& 0.000001   & e-6 \\
nano  & \si{\nano} & 0.000000001& e-9 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This code does not seem to work any longer on TeXLive 21. It produces the error ``Package siunitx Error: Found prefix part with no unit.``.

Comment: @TeXApprentice - Thanks for bringing this issue to my attention. Please see the update I posted at the start of the answer.