# How to convert the macro `\si` in the new version 3 of siunitx?

Tags: siunitx

In the manual, unless I am mistaken, it says to replace `\si` by `\unit`.

But I have this error:

> Package siunitx Error: Found prefix part with no unit.

How can I make this document compatible with the new version 3 of siunitx?

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610,10pt,french]{beamer}

\usepackage[french]{babel} 
\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}  

    
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
%  \sisetup{color = blue}

  \begin{tabular}{l l l}
   kilo $=1000$ & noté \unit{\kilo} &\rule[2mm]{0pt}{5mm} Exemples:\ \unit{\kilo\metre}; \unit{\kilo\gram};% \\
%   hecto $=100$ & \repete{noté} \si{\hecto} &\rule[2mm]{0pt}{5mm}\repete{Exemple:}\ \  \si{\hecto\meter}; \si{\hecto\gram}; \si{\hecto\liter}\\
%   deca $=10$ & \repete{noté} \si{\deca}& \rule[2mm]{0pt}{5mm}\repete{Exemple:}\ \  \si{\deca\meter}; \si{\deca\gram}; \si{\deca\liter}\\
%      déci $=0.1=\dfrac{1}{10}$ & \repete{noté} \si{\deci} & \rule[2mm]{0pt}{5mm}\repete{Exemple:}\ \ \si{\deci\meter}; \si{\deci\gram}; \si{\deci\liter} \\
%   centi $=0.01=\dfrac{1}{100}$ & \repete{noté} \si{\centi} & \rule[2mm]{0pt}{5mm}\repete{Exemple:}\ \ \si{\centi\meter}; \si{\centi\gram}; \si{\centi\liter}\\
%    milli $=0.001=\dfrac{1}{1000}$ & \repete{noté} \si{\milli} & \rule[2mm]{0pt}{5mm}\repete{Exemple:}\ \ \si{\milli\meter}; \si{\milli\gram}; \si{\milli\liter}
  \end{tabular}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\unit{\kilo}` is the culprit: a prefix without unit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, you *can* use `\si` also with `siunitx` version 3, but it's deprecated and is present for back compatibility.

Second: a prefix *must* be followed by a unit; it wasn't enforced in version 2, now it is.

With a little stretch, you can define a `\siprefix` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\NewDocumentCommand{\siprefix}{m}{%
  \unit{#1\nonexistentunitjustforprefixes}%
}
\DeclareSIUnit{\nonexistentunitjustforprefixes}{\relax}

\begin{document}

\siprefix{\kilo}

\end{document}
```

You could actually do `\unit{k}`, but this would defy the purpose of the package.

Comment: You say that `\si` is back compatible but with version 3 `\si{\kilo}` doesn't work while it worked with version 2!

Comment: @AndréC It sort of worked. But the documentation has always been adamant in saying that prefixes must be followed by units.

Comment: If I write `\unit{k}` instead of `\unit{\kilo}`, will the result be identical?

Comment: @AndréC Just type `k`.

Comment: ok, can you add this possibility to your answer?

Comment: @AndréC Added, with a comment.

Comment: it defy the purpose of the package, but it allows me to use `\sisetup{color = blue}` to color all units blue ! How to make it simpler then ?

Comment: @AndréC I've retained the document commands from v2 but I decided not to try to make them 100% compatible, as there are significant changes to the font set up. As such, I retained *exactly* the v2 code using `\usepackage{siunitx}[=v2]` for cases where it's needed.

Comment: @JosephWright Thank you, but why did you decide to make units mandatory? I can understand it for academics, but when teaching children, our first job is to teach them the meaning of prefixes...

Comment: @AndréC The use case of teaching/illustrating prefixes is _very_ specialised. Obviously I have it myself for the package, and I therefore made sure I did have a way to do it in v3: what I wanted to avoid is having a special case in the code for an incredibly rare situation (almost always a dangling prefix is an error).